# SQLite-net and SQLite-WinRT at the same time in Windows runtime apps

Tags: windows, sqlite, windows-runtime, win-universal-app, sqlite-net

Previously I had used SQLITE-NET library for my all sqlite database tasks and it works well. 
But my app has huge number of data to insert and it took a lot of time. So I decided to use SQLITE-WinRT wrapper only where bulk insert is needed as SQLITE-WinRT wrapper seems to provide feature like preparing statements then binding data and then execute them which gives faster processing and increases performance.

In my app, there are lots of CRUD operations that uses SQLITE-NET methods and I left as it is since it is hard to completely switch from SQLITE-NET library to SQLITE-WinRT wrapper.

My app has background task that runs and processes some web-service calls and lot of CRUD operations using only SQLITE-NET library.

Whenever I tried to bulk insert using SQLITE-WinRT wrapper using prepared statements, in case background task is running, it always throws `Busy` exception in SQLITE-NET library. I know its reason, background service does lot of CRUD operations using SLITE-NET library. So while bulk inserting using SQLITE-WinRT wrapper it throws `Busy` exception as the sqlite database is already doing lot of tasks in background using SQLITE-NET.

So, my question is how to handle this situation. Please suggest me some ideas to handle such cases. I thought of two ideas:

- Stopping background service while bulk inserting (In background,
  there is series of long tasks like calling web-service and doing work
  with SQLite db, stopping background service at once might not be
  good idea )
- Closing all SQLITE-NET connection (didn't work as expected though)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

While bulk inserting, I started like this:

```
 string dbPath = "collection.sqlite";
 var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(dbPath);
 var db = new SQLiteWinRT.Database(file);
 await db.OpenAsync(SqliteOpenMode.OpenReadWrite);
 using (var statement = await db.PrepareStatementAsync("INSERT INTO Forms(ServerFormId,FormFileName,FormStatusId,PriorityId) VALUES(?,?,?,?)"))
                {
                    await db.ExecuteStatementAsync("BEGIN TRANSACTION");
                    statement.Reset();
                    statement.BindTextParameterAt(1, "0");
                    statement.BindTextParameterAt(2, formName);
                    statement.BindTextParameterAt(3, formStatusId);
                    statement.BindTextParameterAt(4, priorityId);
                    await statement.StepAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
                await db.ExecuteStatementAsync("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
```

SQLite-WinRT: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andy_wigley/2013/11/21/how-to-massively-improve-sqlite-performance-using-sqlwinrt/

SQLite-net: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/826602/Using-SQLite-as-local-database-with-Universal-Apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that the only option is using *lock* or *semaphore* before accessing the database.

The lock mechanism guarantees that only one thread does inner code block. Other threads synchronously waits.

```
readonly object sync = new object();

void MyMethod() {
    lock (sync) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Semaphore is similar, but the inner code block can be executed maximally by *n* threads.

Please see more info about `SemaphoreSlim` on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.aspx?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP5000527).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate a bit more how to use lock or semaphore?